# Why can't I run `npm install`?

Tags: sqlite, npm-install, package.json

I am trying to complete a project provided by Codecademy's Web Development Skill Path called "Gold Metal Metrics". The goal is to build a web app that uses SQLite. They provide some starter code with the instruction to first run `npm install` to install all of the dependencies, but I cannot even get past this first step because npm keeps throwing errors at me. Here is the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "agoldmedalmetric",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "csv-parse": "^1.2.1",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mocha": "^6.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.6"
  }
}
```

And my part of my error log:

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read https://babeljs.io/env to update!
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated acorn-dynamic-import@2.0.2: This is probably built in to whatever tool you're using. If you still need it... idk
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: The v1 package contains DANGEROUS / INSECURE binaries. Upgrade to safe fsevents v2
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.11.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/masonbennett/Dropbox/My Mac (Mason’s MacBook Air)/Desktop/Programming/programs/github/web_apps/project-5-gold-medal-metrics-start/node_modules/sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3310100/sqlite3.c
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/Users/masonbennett/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/bin/node /Users/masonbennett/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/masonbennett/Dropbox/My Mac (Mason’s MacBook Air)/Desktop/Programming/programs/github/web_apps/project-5-gold-medal-metrics-start/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v108-darwin-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/Users/masonbennett/Dropbox/My Mac (Mason’s MacBook Air)/Desktop/Programming/programs/github/web_apps/project-5-gold-medal-metrics-start/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v108-darwin-arm64 --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
```

I noticed that there were several `npm WARN deprecated` messages, and I figured the best thing to try was to resolve them one at a time. But when I tried to run `npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev` to update `"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"` I was getting the same error messages. Do I really have to reinstall all of these packages on at a time, and will I have to updated all of my starter js files?

Comment: Just fixed it. Apparently sqlite3 was the issue. Once I removed that, I was able to install the other modules just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting by removing the ^ characters in package.json.

That character tells npm to select the latest minor versions of each package, which ideally do not have breaking changes.

By removing it, your should be installing the versions which the author had at the time.

If you were to install them one by one, you'll get the latest versions for all, just as the author likely did when they created it.